# Как в инпуте вместо числового значения поставить, значение placeholder-a инпута по умолчанию!

Tags: javascript, dom

Всем привет! Подскажите как мне во второй функции, сделать так чтобы при обнулении инпутов, вернуть значение placeholder-a данного инпута.

```
<input type="text" class="inputNumber" placeholder="Первое число">
<input type="text" class="inputNumber" placeholder="Второе число">
<input type="text" class="inputNumber" placeholder="Третье число">
<input type="text" class="outputSum" placeholder="Ответ">
<button class="btn">Сумма</button>
<button class="reset-button">Обнулить</button>

var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.inputNumber');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
var sum = document.querySelector('.outputSum');
var resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-button');

var arrElem = Array.from(elem);
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for(var i = 0; i < arrElem.length; i++ ) {
        sum.value = Number(sum.value) + Number(arrElem[i].value);
    }
    return sum.value;
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (sum.value !== 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrElem.length; i++ ){
            arrElem[i].value = 0;
        }
        sum.value = 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: ? в resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function ()


arrElem[i].value = "";
sum.value = "";

Comment: Спасибо, мне казалось что если поставить пустую строку, то ответ выйдет NaN. Надо было попробовать!